# Error installing AWS Cli" No such file or directory: '/usr/local/aws/bin/python'

Tags: python, aws-cli

Hello I'm trying to install aws cli with the command, following the tutorial in the page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

But I'm getting the next error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rodolfosilva/sonatype/lift/muse/./awscli-bundle/install", line 268, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/rodolfosilva/sonatype/lift/muse/./awscli-bundle/install", line 244, in main
    create_install_structure(working_dir, opts.install_dir)
  File "/Users/rodolfosilva/sonatype/lift/muse/./awscli-bundle/install", line 107, in create_install_structure
    create_virtualenv(location=install_dir, working_dir=working_dir)
  File "/Users/rodolfosilva/sonatype/lift/muse/./awscli-bundle/install", line 114, in _create_virtualenv_internal
    run('%s -m venv %s' % (sys.executable, location))
  File "/Users/rodolfosilva/sonatype/lift/muse/./awscli-bundle/install", line 86, in run
    raise BadRCError("Bad rc (%s) for cmd '%s': %s" % (
__main__.BadRCError: Bad rc (1) for cmd '/usr/local/bin/python -m venv /usr/local/aws': Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/aws/bin/python'
```

My phyton version is `Python 3.10.4`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. If I run the same sequence of commands you have included in your question, the install completes successfully (running on Fedora 35, with Python 3.10.4). If you `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/aws /usr/local/bin/aws` and repeat the install, does it continue to fail the same way? It looks like your Python is installed in `/usr/local/bin`; how did you install it?